# C# returning Exception at runtime

Tags: c#

Don't think this is possible but thought I would ask and maybe someone could suggest an alternative technique or pattern.

Say I have a Customer class that has as list of Books which are both pulled seperately from an external source. If the Customer class is successfull but the Books failed to load I don't want to throw an Exception unless the client tries to access the Books property so..

```
this.Books = new List<Book>()
{
    throw new Exception("Books couldn't load because blah blah");
};
```

Is something along these lines possible?

Comment: btw, FCL has a number of special classes for such situation - `ArgumentException`, `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: it's NOt recommended to raise an exception of Exception type. it's a base type for all other exceptions in NET you may rise more specific exception type or create your own custom exception.

Comment: I actually think that InvalidOperationException would be an appropriate exception. From MSDN on InvalidOperationException - An inappropriate call to an object is made, based on the object state.

Answer (score 10):

How about placing this logic into a `Books` property backed off with a private field `books`:

```
public IEnumerable<Book> Books //or public IList<Book> Books
{
    get
    {
        if(this.books == null)
            throw new Exception("Books couldn't load because blah blah");
        return this.books;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good pattern, except for the Exception type. It is way better to throw a subtype (for example `InvalidOperationException`) or implement your own.

Answer (score 4):

In your Books property, add a logic to check whether the collection is loaded:

```
public List<Book> Books { get {
  if (this.books == null) // or any other flag check
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Books are not loaded.");
  return this.books;
} }
```

Comment: Good shout on the exception type, System.Exception shouldn't really be thrown.